# Add a non-Georgian calendar in MATE

Tags: mate-desktop, calendar

I'm using the MATE desktop environment, and one of the things I can attach to the panel is a clock and calendar.

I use non-Georgian dates on a daily basis, and I would like to show another date on the panel.
Does any one know how I can do this?

I can write/get scripts to convert the dates, so the main problem is getting the dates to display on the panel.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Again, do not use backticks to highlight random words. Backticks are for code.